# Citation using Biblatex with XeLaTeX as compiler

Tags: biblatex, xetex, biber

I am using `Biblatex` package and `Biber` as backend. The citations and the bibliography came out fine after I followed the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number). Basically, I had to compile the master/main file running

### `LaTeX`, then `Biber`, then `LaTeX` again

And it worked.

But my problem now is that I have Chinese characters in my text, so I used `XeLaTeX` to compile. Then I thought of trying

### `XeLaTex` masterfile--`Biber` masterfile--`XeLaTeX` masterfile,

but it did not get pass the second step because `Biber` requires a successful `LaTeX` compilation first.

How can I get around this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try `xetex` or `xelatex`? You want `xelatex`. If that isn't the problem, then please provide a short [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Have you seen [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984) just to be sure you're using XeLaTeX correctly. Documents that compile with pdfLaTeX need some modifications to compile with XeLaTeX.

Comment: If you can't get the BibTeX run to succeed because the XeLaTeX run (XeTeX or XeLaTeX? as David Purton says, you very probably want `xelatex`) didn't finish cleanly, the obvious way is to make sure that the XeLaTeX run goes smoothly. Unfortunately, there are a great many things that could be problematic here. You will have to share more about your document with us (best would be a so-called MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 or MWEB https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, moewe.

I just realized what I was doing wrong, and what I accidentally did right.

My first compilation was actually `XeLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX`. If I just run `XeLaTeX`, the `.bcf` file will be created or will remain. (Note: In this first run, none of the `\ref` will work and the output will just show `???`.) After this, I can `Biber` *masterfile.tex* successfully. Finally, I can compile using `XeLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX`. And all the `\ref` commands and citations will work as expected.

Comment: If you don't have an index the sequence XeLaTeX, Biber, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX is enough. No need for `XeLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` (which might run `texify` or some other tool).